# HTML/CSS Modal Dialog: Centering Content of Unknown Size -- Scrolling on Overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a javascript function that creates a modal dialog.  I want the content, which is of unknown or changing size, to be centered horizontally and vertically.  If it outgrows the screen, I want it to scroll.

It is made up of four divs:

The first creates the semi-transparent overlay with the next-highest z-index available when it is created.
The second creates another completely transparent area over the top of that with the display set to table and a z-index higher than the previous overlay.
The third with a display of table-cell
The forth is for the content and has a display of inline-block.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="overlay" style="z-index=1;">
            <div class="modaltable" style="z-index=2;">
                <div class="modalcell">
                    <div class="modalcontent">
                        <p>this is some text</p>
                        <p>this is some text</p>
                        <p>this is some text</p>
                        <p> ... repeat to overflow ... </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

​

```
.overlay
{
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
.modaltable
{
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background: rgb(236, 236, 236); /*Fallback if rgba not supported*/
    background: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0);
    background: none\9;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00ececec, endColorstr=#00ececec); /*IE*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.modalcell
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:rgb(236, 236, 236); /*Fallback if rgba not supported*/
    background:rgba(236, 236, 236, 0);
    background: none\9;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00ececec, endColorstr=#00ececec); /*IE*/
}
.modalcontent
{
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:auto!important;
    background-color:white;
    padding:5px;
}
```

​

I cannot get the scrolling to work. I have searched high and low and can't find a good solution.  Any help is much appreciated.

I've set up a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4K6ug/

Thanks,

Brad

Comment: with percent heights there is no scrolling for divs. Use JS to set divs heights in pixels, and scrollbars will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4K6ug/1/)

You had put `position:fixed` on both `overlay` and `modaltable`. However, those element are nested, so only one should be in such position.

By nesting them, the parent element (`overlay`) contains well, nothing. So it only work on it's size definition (`height:100%;`) and doesn't expand if it's content break the box content (think of it as using `overflow:hidden`). z-index are useless in that case too.

Comment: Thank you. I actually got this to work, but in a very round-about way. I actually didn't intend to nest the three divs in the first div -- the first was just supposed to block the screen.  Had you not pointed that out, I probably would have missed it.  I do need the z-indexes, as these can layer on top of each other (i.e. modals over modals [but I goofed on that too -- using and = instead of a colon -- I'm obviously brain-dead]). Anyway, thanks for the clear explanation.  You rock!

Comment: It's great that you have found a solution to your problem. Since it seems strickly different from what I said (although it helped you), Could you please post your own solution (and accept it)? Thanks!